# Jquery Auto select Menu Item.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i am trying to select navigation item once user click on them and they should remain selected once page load up. I have tried many examples and none is working for me.

Here is what i have in header.

```
<nav id="navigation">

<ul id = "nav-ul">
        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->base?>/Logins/index">item1</a></li>
        <li> <a href="<?php echo $this->base?>/Logins/item2">item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->base?>/Logins/item3">item3</a></li>

</ul>

    </nav>
```

And here is what i have in script.js. Script is added in all files.

**last one i tried**

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('#navigation ul li a').each(function(index) {
        if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
            $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

**Than tried this**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
        .lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    $("#navigation ul li a").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
            $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#navigation ul li a").selected
    })
});
```

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you give details of the problems you had with your examples. Are you trying to say that the selected menu item should remain highlighted after refresh?

Comment: Can you show your css?  It looks like you're adding class "active" in one case and class "selected" in another.  What is the css rule that styles the link to appear as selected and which selector is it supposed to be applied to (i.e., the anchor tag or the list item)?

Comment: @connersz what i want is when user click on navigation item and browser go to that page than it should remain selected.

Comment: @jme11 these are two different examples i tried both one by one and deleted respected css class. But that class does't contain more than background color

Answer (score 0):

this is ypur mark up

```
<ul id = "nav-ul">
    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->base?>/Logins/index"    >item1</a></li>
    <li> <a href="<?php echo $this->base?>/Logins/item2"      >item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->base?>/Logins/item3"      >item3</a></li>
```

then
get the file name

```
filename = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

then by jquery find the anchor tag

```
$("a[href$="+filename +"]").addClass("selected")
```

hope this would help you

Answer (score 0):

For your current html markup, this is the code you'll need in order to achieve the  kind of effect you are looking for.

CSS:

```
ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

a {
    color:Orange;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.active {
    color:red;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function (event) {
        $('#navigation ul li a').each(function (index) {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        });
        $(event.target).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/V5XhN/

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: What i think clss don't add up some other class overrie or something. I it possible to apply css rule. like $(event.target).css('color', 'red'). It only effect at the time of licking but once page loads it does't show up.

Comment: @Shah My fiddle doesn't change pages. I provided it as an example for you to understand how it actually is achieved. If you are changing the page, you must look to add the "active" class on that page. I am not very familiar with php, but there must be way to pass data from one page to another.